# How to set encoding in editor joe based on file type

Tags: joe

I want Java properties files (*.properties) to be opened in ISO8859-1 encoding on my otherwise UTF-8 using linux. Found the ftype.rc, but cannot found out how to configure it.

Comment: i think there is a great default on the [github project from the vendor](https://github.com/iarna/joe-editor/blob/master/rc/ftyperc) for a faster jump look for example for java, I think it might basically `-encoding iso-8859-1` where  might be the right

Comment: @djdomi: Thanks, I checked and on Debian 10 this was even included, I had a Debian 8 where the problem occured. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that newer versions of joe (or at least of Debian starting with Deb 9 or 10) already contain a specialized configuration for .properties files in ftype.rc. This is the excerpt:

```
 Java's .properties
[java_properties]
*.properties
 this is part of the specification:
-encoding iso-8859-1
-pound_comment
-syntax properties
-highlighter_context
```